# Trying to get screenshot of a window

Tags: qt

I'm trying to run this code:

```
QPixmap ss = QScreen::grabWindow((WId) FindWindow(NULL, L"Blacklight Retribution"));
ss.save("haystack.png", "png");
```

but I am getting this error:

```
error: C2352: 'QScreen::grabWindow' : illegal call of non-static member function
```

Comment: Hmm.. getting this error: C2512: 'QScreen' : no appropriate default constructor available :|

Comment: Sorry for the previous misleading. ``Pixmap p = QPixmap::grabWindow(WID)``. See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html)

Comment: Thanks, that works. :) I'm getting this warning on Qt5 though: `class QPixmap __cdecl QPixmap::grabWindow(unsigned int,int,int,int,int) is deprecated, use QScreen::grabWindow() instead. Defaulting to primary screen.` using this line of code: `QPixmap::grabWindow((WId) FindWindow(NULL, L"Blacklight Retribution")).save("haystack.png", "png");`

Comment: Actually as far as I could tell from the manual, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qscreen.html#grabWindow), you could not directly call it.  It's still non-static. I could find a bug report on Qt project about this :)

Comment: You might consider the [Qt5 Screenshot example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/desktop-screenshot.html) and make sure you `#include <QScreen>`.

Comment: That link is dead. Is [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html) same as what you linked to?

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
if (screen)
{
    QPixmap ss = screen->grabWindow((WId) FindWindow(NULL, L"Blacklight Retribution"));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to check `screen`. Primary screen must always exist.

Answer (score 2):

Qt 5 has updated Screenshot example and shootScreen function looks as the following:

```
void Screenshot::shootScreen()
{
    QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    if (const QWindow *window = windowHandle())
        screen = window->screen();
    if (!screen)
        return;

    originalPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
    updateScreenshotLabel();
}
```